# What is the best practice when typing Template Refs in Vue3 with Composition API?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, html5-canvas, vue-composition-api

I have started working on a project and decided to use Vue3 with the Composition API and Typescript. The first step in my project is to render a football field on the screen and I am doing this using the `HTMLCanvasElement`. In order to access its various properties in my `<script>` tag, I set up a template ref for it. As the Vue Docs suggest, I declared it as `const canvas = ref<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null)`. However, now I have a whole bunch of code that is underlined in red, since, well, it depends on the value of `canvas` not being `null`.

My question is: should I just add the `?` flag everywhere the `canvas` is present in code, as in `canvas.value?.width`? Or should I just add `if` statements at the beginning of every method that check wheter `canvas.value` is `null` or not?

This is the TS code. The errors are on the first 3 lines of the `render` method

```js
const canvas = ref<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);

function fitToContainer(canvas : HTMLCanvasElement){
    canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height  = canvas.offsetHeight;
}

function render(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    // Adjusting the canvas to the right dimenstions
    fitToContainer(canvas.value);
    const canvasWidth = canvas.value.width;
    const canvasHeight = canvas.value.height;

    // ---------------- FILL FIELD WITH COLOR ----------------
    ctx.fillStyle = "#3bad59";
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    // ---------------- DRAW LINES ----------------
}
```

Comment: Seems opinion-based, but yeah, just use an `if`. Adding `?` everywhere seems unmaintainable, and the code will still be executing even when there's nothing sensible to be done. You can add the `if` in the caller, though, `if (canvas) { doStuffWithCanvas(); doOtherStuffWithCanvas(); }`.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I ended up doing and it seems good enough for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct time to use the ref is after component mounted,so you need choose the correct time but use ? or if.

```
import { onMounted } from 'vue'; 
// ...your code 
onMounted(()=>{ 
render()
})
```